# how to create navbar without float?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have question about that how to create a navbar without float.
I created something like this:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <nav>
        <ul class="h">
            <li><a href="#">list numeber 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">list numeber 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">list numeber 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">list numeber 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

with this style:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrap {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 100px auto;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav {
    background: yellow;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 15px;

}
ul li:hover {
    background: #ffff99;
    border-bottom: 4px solid red;
    padding: 8px 15px;

}
```

so, i dont like to use `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` in my design. then i delete the clear div and add some css to my style like this:

```
ul.h:after {
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
}
```

but i didnt work!!! :(
how can i fix it using something like above code?

TnX

Comment: in the after.. put `display: block`? Or overflow hidden in the UL, than you can still float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `display:inline-block`?

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/wkQM7/)

**HTML**

```
<nav>
  <ul class="h">
     <li><a href="#">list numeber 1</a></li><li><a href="#">list numeber 2</a></li><li><a href="#">list numeber 3</a></li><li><a href="#">list numeber 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `float:left;` to `display:inline-block;` in your `li` css.

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/rJRBh/

Answer (score 0):

if you dont like floats you can use inline-block, just be careful because inline-block is sensitive to whitespace

you can also use CSS tables

```
ul { display: table; } 
li { display: table-cell; }
```

Comment: can u explain more about `display: table;` and `display: table-cell` ...? TnX

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

We at Oodles Technologies, follow this approach.

First of all, create HTML Structure like this.

1
    Open

Now we use Css so that navbar looks better

```
#close{position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    color: #fff;
}
.nav{width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    left: -100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
ul{float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
li{width: 100%;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
```

After that we will include some jquery functions to show hide our menu

```
$(function(){
    $("#open").click(function(){
        $(".nav").animate({left: "0px"});
    });
    $("#close").click(function(){
        $(".nav").animate({left: "-100%"});
    });
});
```

You can modify this according to your need.
In this way we can create a full screen navbar using css and jquery
Hope It Helps.